# Exclude popups from reload on focus

Tags: javascript

I have a code that makes my web-app reload on focus. I want to exclude the popups because whenever you open the app you get a popup to grab your location and it reloads and causes some issues. Is there a way to not lose focus whenever theres a popup inside of the website?

Here's my code:

```
var blurred = false;
window.onblur = function() { 
  blurred = true; 
};
window.onfocus = function() { 
  blurred && (location.reload()); 
};
```

- Here is a jsFiddle to give an example of what is doing:
  https://jsfiddle.net/o0z62wam/

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to reload specific "element" in dom , so your popups will not be affected.

```
$("#divID").load(location.href+" #divID>*","");
```